# JRSwapFile Virtualizer generating empty file in jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to generate a report in jasper using virtualizer. I am able to generate report but my swap file size in 0kb. I have got some leads to set `parameters.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, false)` but no luck. Empty swap file is getting generated.

I am using

- java 1.8.0_221
- jasperreport 6.5.0

my code snippet

```
JRSwapFileVirtualizer virtualizer = null; 
virtualizer = new JRSwapFileVirtualizer(3, new JRSwapFile("C://jasperoutput", 4096, 1024), true); 
parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, virtualizer);
parameters.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, false);

JRDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(mainList);

JRBeanCollectionDataSource DS = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(subList);



parameters.put("dataSourceParam", DS);

 JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
           parameters, dataSource);

 File outDir = new File("C:/jasperoutput");
   //outDir.mkdirs();

  // JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,
    //  "C:/jasperoutput/SubReport.pdf");

   JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
   exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
   outDir.mkdirs();
    String filename = "C:/jasperoutput/DemoReport.xlsx";
    File outputFile = new File(filename);
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputFile));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputFile));
    SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
    configuration.setIgnoreCellBorder(true);

    exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
    exporter.exportReport();
```

Output swap file screenshot

[image]

Comment: Did you try to generate report without using `JRSwapFileVirtualizer`? Does it work ok?

Comment: Without JRSwapFileVirtualizer also report is generating fine . I am doing a POC for huge records that's why I am trying to use JRSwapFileVirtualizer.